# Database failover configuration in JBOSS

Tags: database, oracle, jboss, connection-string, failover

I am using EAP 6.4.0 version.
I am trying to do the database failover configuration

The following are the connection URLs

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=database1.com)(PORT=1515)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service-1)))

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=database2.com)(PORT=1515)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service-2)))
```

Note: I have two different service names

How can I add the failover configuration (with two different service names)?

Wherever I referred, this is the pattern i am getting

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=database1.com)(PORT=1535))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=database2.com)(PORT=1535)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=common_service_name)))
```

Note: There is only one service name

Answer (score 0):

You must create a common service name.

For example, automatically when the database starts, it runs a trigger or dynamically executes a SQL query.

```
alter system set service_names='common_service_name' scope=memory
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sys.set_svc_name
 AFTER
  STARTUP
 ON DATABASE
DECLARE role VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN

SELECT Database_Role
INTO Role
FROM V$database;
IF Role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system set service_names=''common_service_name'' scope=memory'; END IF;

END;
```